# How to check two SQL records for with one condition?

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I want to add another column to this table which raises a says 'Cash to Electronic' in front on the PersonID if the mode for 1st installment is 'Cash' and mode for 2nd installment in 'Electronic'.

```
PersonID    InstalmentNumber  DateOfInstalment          Mode
50023467    2                   15-Mar-12               Electronic
50023467    1                   15-Feb-12               Electronic
50023468    2                   5-Apr-12                Cash
50023468    1                   5-Mar-12                Cash
50023469    2                   15-Mar-12               Electronic
50023469    2                   15-Mar-12               Electronic
50023469    1                   15-Feb-12               Electronic
50023469    1                   15-Feb-12               Cash
50027967    2                   15-Mar-12               Electronic
```

Expected Output:

```
PersonID    InstalmentNumber  DateOfInstalment          Mode           Flag
50023467    2                   15-Mar-12               Electronic    
50023467    1                   15-Feb-12               Electronic
50023468    2                   5-Apr-12                Cash
50023468    1                   5-Mar-12                Cash
50023469    2                   15-Mar-12               Electronic
50023469    2                   15-Mar-12               Electronic
50023469    1                   15-Feb-12               Cash
50023469    1                   15-Feb-12               Cash           Cash To Electronic
50027967    2                   15-Mar-12               Electronic
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
select distinct t.PersonID,t.InstalmentNumber,t.DateOfInstalment,t.Mode, 
       case 
          when x.PersonID is not null
             and t.Mode = 'Cash'
             and t.InstalmentNumber = 1
            then 'Cash to Electronic'
          else null
       end as Flag
from tab t
left join tab x on x.PersonID = t.PersonID AND
                   x.Mode = 'Electronic' AND
                   x.InstalmentNumber = 2
```

**[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cadc6/4/0)**

Answer (score 0):

Probablylate to the party, but I would use a window function

```
select
    distinct PersonID,
    InstalmentNumber,
    DateOfInstalment,
    Mode,
    case
        when lead(Mode) over(partition by PersonID order by InstalmentNumber) = 'Cash' then 'Cash to Electronic'
        else null
    end as Flag
from tab
```